# Remover espaço entre palavra no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Estou com uma planilha de 7 mil linhas e preciso remover o espaço entre os números. Tentei usar a função `ARRUMAR` ou `TRIM` mas não funcionou.

Na planilha está assim:

11 99999999

eu preciso que fique assim:

1199999999

Existe alguma função que faça isso? Não estou conseguindo encontrar :{

Comment: Antes de qualquer coisa, comece fazendo o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender como a comunidade funciona; depois leia o guia de [Como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) para verificar como pode melhorar sua pergunta e, por fim, acesse a [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) para verificar vários artigos que te lhe ajudarão a entender melhor o site.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde,

Pode utilizar o recurso de **Localizar e Selecionar**, Na guia Página Inicial, no grupo Edição

Ou utilizar uma formula: =SUBSTITUIR(A2; "Vendas"; "Custo")
Exemplo: Substitui Vendas por Custo (Dados de Custo)

Obrigado.

Comment: Pelo  "Localizar e Substituir" eu não estou conseguindo, eu coloco o por exemplo "11 " (sem aspas) e ele não encontra. Como eu faria pra usar esse substituir para 7 mil linhas?

Comment: Aqui funcionou. Selecionei a coluna e apliquei o localizar e substituir exatamente como você fez e disse que ele não encontra.

Comment: @Lucky no localizar vc coloca o espaco e no subsituir nada.

Answer (score 0):

Para remover espaçamento utilize o `SUBSTITUIR` caso for pt-br a instalação.

Ex:
`=SUBSTITUIR(E7;" ";"")`

O `ARRUMAR` serve apenas para espaços antes e depois, entre as palavras ele não processa.

Comment: Estranho que não está removendo os espaços, eu até baixei um negócio chamado "Kutools" que tem uma função de remover todos os espaços, mas não funciona. :(

Comment: Atente-se em utilizar asas duplas e não simples.